# kubectl kustomize on a remote url

Tags: github, kubernetes, kustomize

I want to run some `kubectl apply` commands without downloading the files:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/master/deploy/kubernetes/snapshot-controller/rbac-snapshot-controller.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/master/deploy/kubernetes/snapshot-controller/setup-snapshot-controller.yaml
```

In addition, I also want to run `kubectl kustomize`,`kubectl apply -k`, on the following directory while accessing it as a remote URL: https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/tree/master/client/config/crd

Comment: `kubectl apply -f https://...` you are downloading them, but they are apply on the fly

Comment: I can't use the `-f` option, it's a different case because you can't use `apply -f` with kustomization.yaml. Running `kubectl apply -f` on each file in this directory and then the `kubectl kustomize` fails because this is the syntax: `kubectl apply -k <kustomization_directory>`